# Como ordenar uma coluna de DataTable (jQuery) por dia da semana?

Tags: jquery-datatables

Vindo de uma query utlizando CodeIngniter, os dados relacionados com o dia da semana são convertidos na query nativa:

```
[...], 
Case
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 0 then 'Domingo'
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 1 then 'Segunda'
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 2 then 'Terça'
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 3 then 'Quarta'
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 4 then 'Quinta'
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 5 then 'Sexta'
   when DATEPART(DW, cast(registro.data_registro as date)) = 6 then 'Sabado'
end as DiaSemana,  [...]
```

Uma table simples de html:

```
<table id="tabela_espelho" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content" style="display: none">
  <thead class="flip-content">
   <tr>
    <th title="Matrícula">Matrícula</th>
    <th title="Nome">Nome</th>
    <th title="Data da Inconsistência">Data Inconsist.</th>
    <th title="Dia da Semana">Dia Semana</th>
    <th title="Inconsistência">Inconsistência</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Ao inserir no DataTable, os dias aparecem perfeitamente dentro da coluna correta, escritos de Domingo à Sábado (inclusive, gostaria de ordenar de Segunda - Domingo), mas não é possível ordená-las da forma correta, o ordenamento automático da coluna é por ordem alfabética, mas eu preciso que seja por dia da semana, alguém poderia me ajudar? De **preferência** que **não tenha de alterar a query**, por não ser de minha autoria.

**obs**: **Utilizo o datatable via script com ajax** passando parâmetros via post, com conversores de valores do tipo:

```
{"data": "DiaSemana", "width": "12%"},

{type: 'date-euro', targets: [2]},    //Conversor de data/hora
{type: 'percent', targets: [2]},      //Conversor de porcentagem
```

**Resumindo**:

**O que eu procuro** é a possibilidade de ordenar corretamente de forma Ascendente e Descendente a coluna de dias da semana, com o dia inicial sendo Segunda e o último Domingo, através do método **{type}**, como os conversores acima.

Comment: Matt, encontrei isso no fórum do dataTables: [Sorting on weekdays](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/201/sorting-on-weekdays)

Comment: Já tinha visto esse post mas não consegui tratá-lo sem alterar a query... Mas vou ver com meu superior se ele libera a mudança da query. Acredito que esse tutorial venha a resolver o problema. Daí marco como resolvido. Obrigado até então!